# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 precompile - improve performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got an application running internally on our IIS 8 server. I'm using an Empty ASP.NET 5 Template where I'm using the MVC6, EF7 packages and some others.

I've used Database-First to make objects of a pretty big database with over 200 tables which I am using in my API requests.

This application takes about 2 minutes after launching it and making **the first** request to the api endpoint to compile(i think?). The requests after the first are almost instant.

Also when the IIS server is reset (or after it's recycling) the first request is about 2 minutes again.

When I was using ASP 4.5 (MVC5) I could precompile when publishing. This option seems to have disappeared.

But my real question is: **what can I do to make my application run fast even on the first request?**

Answer (score 0):

When you publish, by default, `dnu` publishes the sources and they are compiled on the fly when the server starts.

You can use the `--no-source` option to precompile everything. That should speed up startup (`--runtime` is optional):

```
dnu publish --no-source [--runtime active|<name of runtime>]
```

Comment: This already speeds up the application alot! What still takes a while is the 'creation' of my DbContext. Is there a way to speed this up by doing the 'creation(mapping?)' of my Entity Framework DbContext?